# Future async from Kotlin library not working

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, flutter

was trying to scan a code using barcode scanner from a library, and put it inside an object.

```
class _abc extends State<abc>{
  String barcode = "";
  Future myfunction() async {
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      await new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      this.barcode = barcode;
      selectedChoice.setters=barcode;
      setState((){}); //refresh
    }
  }
}
```

only this part of the code didnt recognize..

Comment: what's the error you have ?

Comment: no error, just the function wont start even after the wait.

Comment: Future async task and setState cannot be in a wrapper ?

Comment: Have you fallowed "Getting Started" steps from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_scan? And how do you call your function?

Comment: yes , I have.. the apps work perfectly on tutorial code, i suspect the apps freeze because of the async Code...This is how i called the function void _select(Choice choice) {
    if (choice.title=='scan'){myfunction;}}